# Command-line to run executable JAR with configuration

Tags: command-line, java, eclipse, jar

How to run the executable JAR file with a specific configuration?

My code can be run in Eclipse with the run configuration " *9001 12.123.23.43 9001* "

Now export the executable jar file and hope to run it in cmd

When use "**java -jar test.jar 9001 12.123.23.43 9001**", it shows error:
[Picture of error in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDz1b.png) 
so is that command right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UnsupportedClassVersionError error means that you are trying to run your code with a version of Java older than the one you used to compile it.

Version 52.0 is Java 8 so you are trying to run the code with Java 7 or earlier.

Either run the code with Java 8 or change the compilation settings in Eclipse.

There is lots more discussion about this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10382929/2670892) Stack Overflow question.